# Remove a Dimension from Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

If we have a 4D cube with integer keys, and we want to convert the 4D array into a 3D array by keeping the 3rd dimension key $i3 fixed at some value $i30, we can do:

```
// ARRAY REMOVE 3RD INDEX IN 4D
function array_remove($a,$i30){
    $n1=count($a);
    $n2=count($a[0]);
    $n3=count($a[0][0]);
    $n4=count($a[0][0][0]);
    $a1=array();
    for ($i1=0;$i1<$n1;$i1++){
        $a1[$i1]=array();
        for ($i2=0;$i2<$n2;$i2++){
            $a1[$i1][$i2]=array();
            for ($i4=0;$i4<$n4;$i4++){
                $a1[$i1][$i2][$i4]=$a[$i1][$i2][$i30][$i4];
            }
        }
    }
    return $a1;
}
```

How can I extend this function to remove any dimension, i.e. removing $ik to $ik0 $array_remove($a,$ik,$ik0), or for arrays of any dimension not 4D only $array_remove($a,$n,$ik,$ik0)?

Comment: Please provide realistic sample input and your exact desired output by [edit]ing your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: This problem is esoteric enough, and lacking in utility enough, that I expect is it is a homework assignment. If I am wrong, I will dive into this interesting problem with you. But as a hint, the innermost loop can just be replaced with `$a1[$i1][$i2]=$a[$i1][$i2][$i30]`

Comment: Even if this is a homework question, Stack Overflow still expects a [mcve] in the question -- not only to invite more correct answers, but for the benefit of future researchers to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't resist.

Given an n-dimensional array, return an array of n-1 dimensions, using a particular value for the replaced dimension:

```
$source = [
    1 => [
        'a' => ['p', 'q', 'r'],
        'b' => ['s', 't', 'u'],
        'c' => ['v', 'w', 'x'],
    ],
    2 => [
        'a' => ['e', 'f', 'g'],
        'b' => ['h', 'i', 'j'],
        'c' => ['k', 'l', 'm'],
    ],
];

$result = array_select($source, 2, 'b');
```

`$result` is now:

```
[
    1 => ['s', 't', 'u'],
    2 => ['h', 'i', 'j'],
]
```

The second dimension has been replaced with the values that used to have index `'b'` in that dimension.

Nested looping with arbitrary depth suggests recursion - traverse the array down to the depth where we perform surgery:

```
function array_select(array $source, int $dimension, $value) {
    
    // TODO: before starting recursion, make sure that $dimension >=1
    // and the actual depth of $source is > $dimension

    if ($dimension === 1) {
        // return the value at that depth, empty if not set
        return $source[$value] ?? [];
    } else {
        
        foreach ($source as $index => $subset) {
            $source[$index] = array_select($subset, $dimension - 1, $value);
        }

        return $source;
    }
}
```

Once the recursion reaches the desired depth, it just needs to return whatever is at the given value.

This actually has fewer lines of code than the original constrained version.

Removing the indicated index is similar:

```
$result = array_remove($source, 2, 'b');
```

`$result` is now:

```
[
    1 => [
        'a' => ['p', 'q', 'r'],
        'c' => ['v', 'w', 'x'],
    ],
    2 => [
        'a' => ['e', 'f', 'g'],
        'c' => ['k', 'l', 'm'],
    ],
]
```

To remove the indicated index, when we get to the "depth of surgery", we return the array with all except the named index:

```
function array_remove(array $source, int $dimension, $value) {
    
    // TODO: before starting recursion, make sure that $dimension >=1
    // and the actual depth of $source is > $dimension

    if ($dimension === 1) {

        // return all but the value at that depth
        return array_filter($source, function ($key) use ($value) {
            return $key != $value;
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    } else {
        
        foreach ($source as $index => $subset) {
            $source[$index] = array_remove($subset, $dimension - 1, $value);
        }

        return $source;
    }
}
```

Comment: This kind of operation appears often when working with multidimensional matrices, such as those in MATLAB. In this case, it is for an array of filters of an automated image, hence NxFxIxJxK arrays. As I see, this is the 'array_select' operator, which takes the 2nd dimension and fixes it in the value 'b'. How can I modify this code for keep everything but the selected, such as exactly the opposite, taking the 2nd dimension and removing the value 'b'? i.e. array_remove($source,2,{'a','c'})

Comment: If all your indices are numeric like a traditional array, and you want to keep the indices sequential, you might need to do `array_values(array_filter(...))`

Comment: If there are a lot of filters you might want to apply, I just stopped myself from adding some fun code to simplify that.